# Imported animation from mixamo to unity causes left hand to act unusual

Tags: animation, import, unity

Edit: I realised after I posted this question that it is on the blender stack exchange and this question is not actually blender related, however, I understand the files I am working with were designed and exported from blender so I feel that this is a relevant location for this question.

Edit: The eagle eyed viewers may realise that the icon shown in the first image indicates that I have added "Animation Rigging" inside of Unity. I added this to try and correct the issue, I can assure you that this is not the cause of the issue.

I am a software developer by trade and have little experience with the 3D modelling, rigging, texturing and animation pipeline.

I am just currently creating a hobby 3d shooter project and have imported a model/animation pack from mixamo in to unity.

Everything seems to have been imported correctly and all bones labelled correctly and in the correct position when in T-Pose in the game.

The problem:

When I start the game with the "Running While Aiming" animation everything works fine, apart from the left hand seems to be inverse in some way, see screenshots below:

This first image is the character in T-Pose showing the hands are correctly modeled.

[image]

This next image shows the character when the game is running and the "Running While Aiming" animation is active. As you can see, the left hand is in an unusual position with the "left hand pinky" finger being on the left of the left hand, when in fact the fingers shoulder be the other way round.

[image]

I have made no alterations to the model, the armature or animations. I imported everything to get going directly from mixamo as a package. I tried importing as a regular .fbx and as Unity .fbx and it has made no difference.

I would really appreciate some help on this if possible. I am a software developer by trade and am trying to create this hobby project to further my game programming skills.

Thanks in advance for any help or feedback provided.

Answer (score 1):

once I found one solution, when exporting an animation at the beginning should be T pose, 0 frame T pose, 1 frame our animation, 2 or 3 frame our animation, in Unity we start cropping the animation with 2 or 3 frames

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen every so often with Mixamo and Unity.  The answer is: when you import the rig, use "copy from other avatar" instead of "create from this model" and use the avatar for the base character.